# Intervention Image encode file extension

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm trying to change all images uploaded to png format. I'm using the [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/api/encode) package for Laravel, and calling the encode function. Image Files are not changing to .png

Here is my upload script: (*Everything is uploading, resizing and appears to be compressing. Just not converting to a png file*)

```
if($request->hasFile('listing_image')){
    $classifiedImg = $request->file('listing_image');
    $filename = 'listing'.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$classifiedImg->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Image::make($classifiedImg)->encode('png', 65)->resize(760, null, function ($c) {
        $c->aspectRatio();
        $c->upsize();
        })->save(public_path('/images/users/listing-images/' . $filename));

    $classified->listing_image = $filename;
    $classified->save();
}else{
    $classified->save();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in this section:

```
Image::make($classifiedImg)->encode('png', 65)->resize(760, null, function ($c)...
```

OR is this causing the issue:

```
getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: yes, the *OR is this causing the issue* part is true, try to check your image is valid png or not after passed into the code. i think its just the extension misled you. you could use [this page](http://checkfiletype.com/) to test fyi.

Comment: @BagusTesa thanks for taking time out to help. Are you saying I need to check the MIME type so I can change all images to a png?

Comment: well, no, first thing to do, check that the output is indeed a `png` and the force the filename's extension as `png` instead of using `getClientOriginalExtension()`.

Comment: @BagusTesa okay got you. The image I uploaded is a .jpg. When check  using the site you provided, it returns this:

`File Type: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, comment: "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality = 90"
MIME Type: image/jpeg
Suggested file extension(s): jpeg jpg jpe`

I also tried to to remove the quality on the png format because I read that quality doesn't affect png's. Also tried png to jpg. Still didn't work.

Comment: wait, the one you tested on that page, the file uploaded..? not the result when passed into the `->encode('png')` one..? the one located on `public_path('/images/users/listing-images/' . $filename)`..

Comment: @BagusTesa both images are jpg. The original image I uploaded and the returned image after uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks BagusTesa, you were correct. This was causing the issue.

```
getClientOriginalExtension();
```

To get the extension to convert. I needed to add the extension to the file name.

Change this line:

```
$filename = 'listing'.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$classifiedImg->getClientOriginalExtension()
```

To This:

```
$filename = 'listing' . '-' . uniqid() . '.png';
```